# Scrapy XPath doesn't get all links in page while Chrome does

Tags: python, google-chrome, xpath, scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get all links on a page 'https://www.jumia.com.eg' using scrapy.

The code is like this:

```
all_categories = response.xpath ('//a')
```

But I found a lot of missing links in the results.

The count of the results is 242 links.

When I tried Chrome developer tools, I got all the links, the count of the results was 608 with the same selector xpath (//a).

[image]

Why doesn't Scarpy get all the links using the mentioned selector while Chrome does?

Comment: The other links are loaded via javascript.

Comment: I'm now aware about this problem. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Try the suggestions in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#selecting-dynamically-loaded-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem is because data is loaded using Javascript as Justin commented.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the website is using reCAPTCHA.

If you type: `view(response)` in scrapy shell, you would noticed that you are actually parsing the reCAPTCHA page (which explains the unexpected `a` tags):

[image]

You can try solving the reCAPTCHA (not sure how easy that would be, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137559/how-do-i-set-up-scrapy-to-deal-with-a-captcha) might help)... Alternatively you can run your **scraper** from a proxy, such as [Crawlera](https://www.scrapinghub.com/crawlera/) which uses rotating IPs... I have not used Crawlera but according to their website, it retries the page several times (with different IPs) until it hits a clean page.